# unexpected callback in node.js

Tags: node.js

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("demo1.html", function (err, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write(data);
      return res.end();
    });
}).listen(80);
```

Error :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't check for an error in the callback of `readFile`. If there is an error, `data` will be `undefined` and `res.write(data)` throws the error you see.

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("demo1.html", function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.writeHead(404);  //or whatever status code you want to return
      } else {
          res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
          res.write(data);
      }
      return res.end();
    });
}).listen(80);
```